# How to get RSA_KEY_URL in ccavenue mobikul sdk

Tags: android, ccavenue

I am using the ccavenue payment gateway Mobile_Integraion_Kit.
But I m a doubt how to get this `RSA_KEY_URL` and what is the use of it in making payment.

Answer (score 0):

if u r using Non-Shameless Process
follow the Steps:

Getting the RSA_Key:

1.your company-server need to register in ccavenue server for getting the rsakey.

2.once u get the rsa-key in your mobile u need to encrypt with money and currency(base64 format)  and  u need to hit their server for getting the billing page.